# Usage of ''and' in "hours and minutes"

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

> A day is the exact length of time it takes the earth to turn around one time.
>   A year is the length of time the earth takes to travel around the sun one time.
>   The Egyptians did not think about these scientific facts.
>   For them, 12 of their 30-day months made a year, but 360 days do not make a full year.
>
> What did they do about these problems?
>   They made a five-day holiday at the end of each year.
>   But even adding five holidays did not make the Egyptians' yearly calendar right.
>   It takes the earth a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun.
>   To be exact, it takes 365 days, 5 hours, 48 minutes and 46 seconds.
>   For a long time people did not add these extra hours **and** minutes and seconds.

Explain it to me why "and" is used between "hours and minutes" instead of comma.

Comment: I'm not sure about the source of your sentence, but it's just a matter of style. For example, *"We ate well and cheaply and drank well and cheaply and slept well and warm together and loved each other."* — Ernest Hemingway.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a lot of the preceding context from the source (a "reading practice" exercise in a textbook). Given the preceding line, the polysyndeton seems to me a very good choice, but I haven't been able to put my finger on the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly stylistic

> hours and minutes and seconds
>   hours, minutes, and seconds

are equivalent.

In any positive list of items it is possible to add "and" between each item

> I like apples and oranges and pears and bananas.
>   *I like apples, oranges, pears, and bananas.*

however, the extra "and"s are usually excluded for brevity.

In a list of negative items, "nor" must be included

> I neither like apples nor oranges nor pears nor bananas.